# Best book for learning sensor fusion, specifically regarding IMU and GPS integration.

Tags: physics

I have posted this in MathOverflow because the subject is primarily Math related.

I have a requirement of building an Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) from the following sensors:

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Magnetometer

I must integrate this data to derive the attitude of the sensor platform and the external forces involved (eg. subtract tilt from linear acceleration).

I must then use this information to compliment a standard GPS unit to provide higher consistent measurements than can be provided by GPS alone.

I do understand the basic requirements of this problem:

- Integrate sensors. (To cancel noise, subtract acceleration).
- Remove noise. (Kalman filter)
- Integrate IMU measurement into GPS.

Whilst there are various libraries currently around that would do this for me (http://code.google.com/p/sf9domahrs/) I need to understand the mechanisms involved to a level where I am able to explain the techniques to other individuals after I have implemented the solution.

I have been looking at the following resources, but I am unsure which I should go for...
I need something covering Sensor Fusion, Filtering, IMU, Integration.

[Multisensor-Fusion-Integration-Intelligent-Systems](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Multisensor-Fusion-Integration-Intelligent-Systems/dp/3642100570/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1333461040&sr=8-7)

[Positioning-Systems-Inertial-Navigation-Integration](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Positioning-Systems-Inertial-Navigation-Integration/dp/0470041900/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1333461040&sr=8-4)

[Mechatronics-Intelligent-Systems-Off-road-Vehicles](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mechatronics-Intelligent-Systems-Off-road-Vehicles/dp/184996467X/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1333461040&sr=8-11)

[Autonomous-Flying-Robots-Unmanned-Vehicles](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Autonomous-Flying-Robots-Unmanned-Vehicles/dp/4431538550/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1333462213&sr=8-5)

I hope someone experienced in this area can provide any recommendations.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's *the* best book, but T&DA by Bar-Shalom is considered a standard reference for problems of this kind, AFAIK.

[http://www.amazon.com/Tracking-data-association-Yaakov-Bar-Shalom/dp/B0006YT0HY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006YT0HY)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend "Applied Optimal Estimation", edited by Arthur Gelb.  It won't answer all your questions, but I think it will help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn the mathematical theory of sensor fusion I strongly recommend you invent it.

There are good engineering books, including the ones cited in the answers, on several different aspects of sensor fusion. A mathematical theory doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Really, right on!  And I'll help!  My email address is in my profile!